# Need to run UserControls as seperate from each other in Main Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I have Main Form which consist of FlowLayoutPanel and this FlowLayoutPanel contain several UserControls Classes named as EffectGroupUserControl, and each EffectGroupUserControl further contain several SingleEffectUserControl as shown in picture below:
[image: Form Containing User Controls]

Each EffectGroupUserControl have its own variables and functions, and inside EffectGroupUserControl the SingleEffectUserControl has its own variables and functions,
The problem I am facing is that when I do something in EffectGroupUserControl[0] it also affect the EffectGroupUserControl[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/605KM.png), I want them to run separately without interfering with each other.

Below is full Code for `EffectGroupUserControl`, there may be several `EffectGroupUserControl` in main form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace water_fountain2
{
    public partial class EffectGroupUserControl : UserControl
    {
        int EffectGroupUserControl_tableRow = 0;
       
        

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return cp;
            }
        }
        public EffectGroupUserControl()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            InitializeComponent();
            Add_SingleEffectUserControl();
          
            

        }
       


        private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #region Button For Adding SingleEffectUserControl to EffectGroupUserControl
        //------------------ Add Button for adding Single Effects -------------
        private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Visible = false;
            tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            //get a reference to the previous existent 
            RowStyle temp = tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1];
            //add a new RowStyle as a copy of the previous one
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(temp.SizeType, temp.Height));
            //increase panel rows count by one
            ;
            this.Height += 30;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(button_add, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(label_timing, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);
            Add_SingleEffectUserControl();
            tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
            tableLayoutPanel1.Visible = true;
        }

        //------------- Method for Adding Single Effect Called by Add Button ----------------------
        private void Add_SingleEffectUserControl()
        {
            SingleEffectUserControl singleeffectUsercontrol = new SingleEffectUserControl(this)
            {
                Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF,
            };
            
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(singleeffectUsercontrol, 2, EffectGroupUserControl_tableRow);
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(singleeffectUsercontrol, 7);
            EffectGroupUserControl_tableRow++;

            singleeffects_list.Add(singleeffectUsercontrol);

        }
        #endregion


        #region Remove SingleEffectUserControl from EffectGroupUserControl



        //--------------------- Remove SingleEffectUserControl from EffectGroupUserControl------------------
        public void Remove_SingleEffectUserControl()
        {
            int SingleEffect_index = 0;   //SingleEffect_index for current row
            bool ctl_deleted = false;     // bool value  for SingleEffectUserControl control deleted

            foreach (var seUc_list in singleeffects_list)    // loop in SingleEffectUserControl list for finding which row's cross button clicked
            {
                SingleEffectUserControl singleeffect_Uc = singleeffects_list[SingleEffect_index]; // get SingleEffectUserControl control from list
                if (singleeffect_Uc.Del_SingleEffectUserControl == true)           // If This SingleEffectUserControl's cross button?
                {
                    RemoveArbitraryRow(tableLayoutPanel1, SingleEffect_index);    // Yes Remove that Row
                    singleeffects_list.RemoveAt(SingleEffect_index);
                    ctl_deleted = true;                                           // control has been deleted
                    singleeffect_Uc.Del_SingleEffectUserControl = false;
                    break;                                                        // get out of loop
                }
                SingleEffect_index++;                                            // increment index if this is not the row that fire cross button
            }



            if (ctl_deleted == true)                           // If Control is deleted from above then process below
            { 
                tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(button_add, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);   // set label & button span
                tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(label_timing, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);
                this.Height -= 30;                                                      // set height after deleted row
                EffectGroupUserControl_tableRow--;                                      
            }
        }

        // ---------- Code for Deleting Specific Row is below --------------------------- 
        public void RemoveArbitraryRow(TableLayoutPanel panel, int rowIndex)
        {
            if (rowIndex >= panel.RowCount)
            {
                return;
            }

            // delete all controls of row that we want to delete
            for (int i = 2; i < panel.ColumnCount; i++)   // start from column 2 for SingleEffectUserControl 
            {
                var control = panel.GetControlFromPosition(i, rowIndex);
                panel.Controls.Remove(control);
            }

            // move up row controls that comes after row we want to remove
            for (int i = rowIndex + 1; i < panel.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j < panel.ColumnCount; j++)       // start from column 2 for SingleEffectUserControl 
                {
                    var control = panel.GetControlFromPosition(j, i);
                    if (control != null)
                    {
                        panel.SetRow(control, i - 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            var removeStyle = panel.RowCount - 1;

            if (panel.RowStyles.Count > removeStyle)
                panel.RowStyles.RemoveAt(removeStyle);

            panel.RowCount--;
        }
        #endregion

        // Create List for Holding SingleEffectUserControl
        private List<SingleEffectUserControl> singleeffects_list = new List<SingleEffectUserControl>();



    }
}
```

Below is full code for `SingleEffectUserControl`, It Sets Flag when cross button is clicked and execute function of `EffectGroupUserControl`(Parent of `SingleEffectUserControl`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.TextBox;


namespace water_fountain2
{


    public partial class SingleEffectUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public bool Del_SingleEffectUserControl = false;
        public EffectGroupUserControl EffectGroupUserControl { get; }


        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return cp;
            }
        }

        public SingleEffectUserControl(EffectGroupUserControl effectGroupUserControl)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            EffectGroupUserControl = effectGroupUserControl;

        }



        private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void devices_comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (devices_comboBox.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Clear();
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("Change Pump Capacity");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("Shooting Repeatly");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("Go High then Low");
                    from_textBox.Enabled = true;
                    to_textBox.Enabled = true;

                    break;

                case 1:
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Clear();
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("ON in Groups Repeatly");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("ON from inside to outside");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("ON from Left to Right");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("OFF from outside to inside");
                    from_textBox.Enabled = false;
                    to_textBox.Enabled = false;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Clear();
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("Red");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("Green");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("Blue");
                    effects_comboBox.Items.Add("Pink");
                    from_textBox.Enabled = false;
                    to_textBox.Enabled = false;
                    break;

            }
        }
        //-------------- Allow Text Boxes to Only Accept Number-------------
        private void from_textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void to_textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void timeON_textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void timeOFF_textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void remove_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Del_SingleEffectUserControl = true;
            EffectGroupUserControl.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl();

        }


        public string Get_to_textbox
        {
            get
            {
                return to_textBox.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                to_textBox.Text = value;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Please note that problem get solved by adding `this` in `EffectGroupUserControl`:

```
    SingleEffectUserControl singleeffectUsercontrol = new SingleEffectUserControl(this)
    {
        Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF,
    };
```

and these lines in `SingleEffectUserControl`:

```
public bool Del_SingleEffectUserControl = false;
public EffectGroupUserControl EffectGroupUserControl { get; }


protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}

public SingleEffectUserControl(EffectGroupUserControl effectGroupUserControl)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    EffectGroupUserControl = effectGroupUserControl;

}
    private void remove_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Del_SingleEffectUserControl = true;
        EffectGroupUserControl.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl();

    }
```

I am adding `SingleEffectUserControl` to `TableLayoutPanel` of `EffectGroupUserControl`, Is this is the reason that `Parent` property is not working?

Comment: If you have used static properties and/or Fields and methods that use them, then change those to instance properties and/or Fields etc. -- Otherwise explain, possibly posting the related code, what *affect one another* means, in your case

Comment: Can you tell me what you did? From what you're saying there's a good chance that some events of these two EffectGroupUserControls overlap. I'll be happy to continue helping you with your issues. Please add the code that produces the error though, give me a minimal implementation use case.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Thank you for your time, I have edited the question and post the code, all doing well with One EffectGroupUserControl but when I add second EffectGroupUserControl, the cross button malfunctioning in SingleEffectUserControl

Comment: In your `SingleEffectUserControl`, you have this line: `EffectGroupUserControl.Instance.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl();`. If you have MULTIPLE `EffectGroupUserControl`s on your form as shown, how can using an `Instance` variable get the correct one?...

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I think this is the right point as suggested by you So is there is any way other than Instance?

Comment: If each `SingleEffectUserControl` is contained DIRECTLY by `EffectGroupUserControl`, then you can do `EffectGroupUserControl g = this.Parent as EffectGroupUserControl;` to get the correct Group Control. Then you can use `g.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl();`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind When I declare `EffectGroupUserControl g = this.Parent as EffectGroupUserControl;` in `SingleEffectUserControl` I got an Error of CS0027:Keyword `this` is not available in current context

Comment: Was `remove_button_Click()` not in the `SingleEffectUserControl` control?

Comment: @Idle_Mind `remove_button_Click()` is in `SingleEffectUserControl` control

Comment: If it's in a UserControl, then `this` should be working there...unless you're not describing the problem correctly.

Comment: Is the REMOVE button not inside the `SingleEffectUserControl`?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you've already stated that `remove_button_Click()` is in fact inside `SingleEffectUserControl`. Put my code, `EffectGroupUserControl g = this.Parent as EffectGroupUserControl;` and `g.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl();`, inside the `remove_button_Click()` method.

Comment: @Idle_Mind you may right but where should I place statement `EffectGroupUserControl g = this.Parent as EffectGroupUserControl;` in Constructor or in Class definition or in `remove_button_Click()`of `SingleEffectUserControl`?

Comment: Inside `remove_button_Click()`...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I put your code inside `remove_button_click()` and now when I execute it then it throws null exception `g was null`

Answer (score 0):

As Idle_Mind said, when you created the sub-control SingleEffectUserControl of EffectGroupUserControl, it seems that you did not consider the relationship between the upper and lower layers.

When creating parent instances in a function, you can pass a reference to the parent instance to each instance instead of using a static instance.

Refer to my previous answer

Modify in: EffectGroupUserControl

```
private void Add_SingleEffectUserControl()
{
    SingleEffectUserControl singleeffectUsercontrol = new SingleEffectUserControl(this) // Pass reference of parent EffectGroupUserControl
    {
        Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF,
    };

    // Rest of the code
}
```

Modify in: SingleEffectUserControl

```
private Control parentControl; 

public SingleEffectUserControl( parentControl) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
   parentControl = this.parent;
}

private void remove_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Del_SingleEffectUserControl = true;
   parentControl.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl(); 
}
```

Comment: It generate error in `SingleEffectUserControl` when I modify the Constructor as defined by you, the error is `CS0246 The type or namespace name 'parentControl' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)`

Comment: also did not find the function in `parentControl.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl();`

Comment: and in `SingleEffectUserControl singleeffectUsercontrol = new SingleEffectUserControl(this)` adding `this` also generate error `CS1503:Argument1: cannot convert from water_fountain2.EffectGroupUserControl to 'parentControl'`.

Comment: [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) class is a base class in winform, there is no chance you need to add it . You seem to have parentControl as a class, which here is just an instance of type Control. maybe need to be `parentControl.Controls.Remove_SingleEffectUserControl();`

Comment: I am adding each `SingleEffectUserControl` to `EffectGroupUserControl`'s TableLayoutpanel, Is that the reason I am seeing these error related to Parent Control?

Comment: @AdilAhmed If you could post the minimal instantiation code for your SingleEffectUserControl and EffectGroupUserControl's reproducible problem, I hope I can solve your problem very quickly. It's currently difficult to directly reproduce your problem. The code you posted appears to be an abbreviated version.

Comment: I have updated the question with complete code, Kindly check if you can understand the problem, Thanks

Comment: @AdilAhmed I took a close look at your code. You could try to create an event that draws all controls from the list. When creating and deleting controls, directly redraw all controls from the list. Should solve your method and make the code a lot cleaner. I haven't sorted out my code yet, so I need to reply next time.

Comment: I am adding `SingleEffectUserControl` in `tableLayoutPanel` of `EffectGroupUserControl`, Is that is the reason `EffectGroupUserControl` is not showing as parent of `SingleEffectUserControl` ?

Comment: Can you show the designer? I'm not quite sure how you use them. Is your singleEffectUserControl control placed in the tableLayoutPanel? It doesn't matter who is his parent, it just needs to be able to identify and delete it correctly. Are you still stuck on this issue? I may reply to this question in a few hours.

Comment: Yes, my 'SingleEffectUserControl' is in tableLayoutPanel of `EffectGroupUserControl`, issue get resolved by adding `public EffectGroupUserControl EffectGroupUserControl { get; }` in `SingleEffectUserControl`, It was the suggestion given by Visual Studio Editor. But I want to know why parent function not working here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the breakdown in communication is.

You've stated:

> @Idle_Mind remove_button_Click() is in SingleEffectUserControl control

Here's a simple `SingleEffectUserControl`:

[image]

Here is the complete code for `SingleEffectUserControl`:

```
public partial class SingleEffectUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SingleEffectUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void remove_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EffectGroupUserControl g = this.Parent as EffectGroupUserControl;
        g.Controls.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Here is `EffectGroupUserControl`:

[image]

Along with the complete code for `EffectGroupUserControl`:

```
public partial class EffectGroupUserControl : UserControl
{
    public EffectGroupUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Here's my main Form with two `EffectGroupUserControl` on it:

[image]

And here is the `SingleEffectUserControl` being removed from the corresponding `EffectGroupUserControl` when the Remove Button is clicked:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and detailed answer, I got the concept but I don't why I am getting the null exception for `g was null`

Comment: There are only two possibilities I can think of. Either (1) You put the code in the wrong place, or (2) What you described doesn't match what you designed. We can't see your code and/or design unless you place it in your original question above. Give us more details. Good luck.

Comment: I am Putting full code of both `EffectGroupUserControl` & `SingleEffectUserControl` in question.

Comment: If possible Kindly check my question I have edited, Thanks